# How to beat valkyrie in defending cc?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I was excited to find a base with 500k elixir, gold and 4k dark elixir, and I had my strongest army composition. I was disappointed however, when 20 wizards, barbarian king and heal spell was unable to take out the Valkyrie in defending clan castle.

How can you attack Valkyrie? Usually I try to make a circle around the defending troops, but this doesn't work as they would move in so they were close together and the Valkyrie would spin around and take them out. With wizards their range isn't super long and they take time to reload, and Valkyrie are so fast it was like they didn't have time to attack.

I guess the lesson is to always carry a poison spell.

Comment: Poison spell is pretty much a MUST for every army composition.

Comment: Ill soon write a detailed answer, but suffice to say, like most have pointed, try bringing a couple of minions with you, (assuming you are th7+). Of course you may not have minions with you, so I would always recommend bringing atleast TWENTY archers. Make a wide spread circle of archers while dropping a poison at the same time. This will contain the valk within the poison enough to kill it off. Happy Clashing!

Comment: @PrittBalagopal sometimes there isn't room for a poison spell for example right now with the dragon sale: I use 4 lightening spells and a earthquake spell, and another earthquake spell in cc. This way I can take out 2 airdefense and unleash the dragons.

Comment: killing valks won't be an issue for drag attacks. Besides why do you bring quake in c? Better off bringing a haste spell with maxed out loons, they are great at taking down air defences and other defences.

Comment: I bring earthquake in clan c as it takes two lightenings and a quake to take out air defense.

Comment: You need 2 lightning and 1 quake to take down ad. Why bring extra quake in cc? You can train your own quake, along with 2 lightning and a rage. Bring a haste in cc

Comment: "You need 2 lightning and 1 quake to take down ad" exactly x2 takes out two ad

Comment: Oh my bad, I thought you were th8. If you're th9, then you're right. However I wouldn't recommend using dragons in th9, unless you're new to th9, or you like bullying th8s. There are so man better compositions you can try like LaLoon, GoHo, GoVaHo, GoLaLoon, HogLoon, GoVaLo.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal it's been a while since I tried them, but I stay away from anything involving balloons. When I used them they were so week they would get taken out before they did any damage. But I think they may have updated the game to fix this (anyone know?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valkyries are one of the strongest clan troops for defending against other ground troops, however they are vulnerable to any flying troop, as they cannot attack any unit that is flying. I would suggest dropping a wizard or two from your army and replacing them with a few minions, or dropping 3 and replacing them with a minion and a baby dragon.

When attacking, I would suggest sending in a hog/giant/loon to pull any clan troops out of the clan castle. Then drop a wizard or archer to lure the clan troops out to the side or the corner of the base where your troops are out of range of defenses. Once you have the troops at the corner, you have a few options. If they have nothing to attack your flying troops (minions or baby drag), you can just drop them and let them take out the clan troops, or you can drop a poison and a few wizards/archers to kill them.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to kill a valkyrie(Assuming you have already lured her out of cc to a corner away from defenses)

1. If you don't have poison or minions or any air troops other than
   balloons, you can either kill valkyrie with a circle of archers or
   you can deploy a giant and as the valkyrie follows the giant, you
   can deploy archers or wiz behind her to kill her.
2. If you have poison, drop poison and deploy barbarians or archers to keep valkyrie inside the poison range, also a few wizards or archers to kill valkyrie if needed.
3. If you don't have poison, you can use barbarians or archers to keep her at a spot while a dragon, baby-dragon or minions kill her.

Update:

[Video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NNWAGX2DIW4)

You can use wiz instead of archers or both in the method used in the video.

For higher th players: [Video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTOaxyHKfOc)

Comment: Is there a trick to using wizards? When I tried them it didn't work. It may have been better to drop them all at once so when a few are getting chopped the others are getting ready to fire.

Comment: @northerner you can deploy them in a circle around the valkyrie, just like we make a circle of archers to kill her. I'll try to find a video and update you.

Comment: Further point to this answer, while for killing cc drags, 12 archers may be enough, but for valks, they are much faster and so you would need at least 20 archers

Comment: For the 'wizard trick' make a small circle of archers around the valk, but don't let the valks kill multiple archers in a shot. This will contain the valk within a small space. Now drop 2 or 3 wizards at a distance and watch it incenerate the axe-lady.